# Didn't receive post data from alamofire post? help me

Tags: ios, post, swift, alamofire

**The server can't receive the post data, why？ did something wrong in my codes, thanks**

```
 // post data
let parameters : [String: AnyObject] = [
                        "uuid" : "731DCD02-1E54-4D28-94F3-D47B7A9D62F4",
                        "sid" : "b172f2697e717d14134d43f477761382",
                    ]         
 //init request    
 self.request = Alamofire.request(
                        "POST",
                        "http://test.cnjob.com/test/index/test",
                        parameters: parameters,
                        encoding:ParameterEncoding.JSON)
 //response
 self.request?.responseString { (request, response, body, error) in{

        println("---\nrequest--------------------------------->" +
            "\n\n\(request)\nresponse------------------------->" +
            "\n\n\(response)\nbody---------------------------->" +
            "\n\n\(body)\nerror------------------------------->" +
            "\n\n\(error)")

 }
```

//
Server code as

```
public function test(){

    sk_base::load_sys_class('logs')->add(date("ymd").'filesDATA',var_export($_REQUEST,true));

    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$_REQUEST));
}
```

//
**results:(the data is empty,why?)**

response--------------------------------------------------->

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f845bd63cb0> { URL: http://xxx/test/index/test } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 22;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 16 Oct 2014 06:23:23 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.12";
} })
```

body----------------------------------------------------->

```
Optional("{**\"data\":[]**}\r\n")
```

error----------------------------------------------------->
nil
Server

Comment: `200 Status code` means successful response. May be there is no data available for this parameters.

Comment: but server did not receive any data, i check the code in Alamofire, the parameters are all in (JSON DATA).

Comment: did something wrong in my php codes?

Comment: just use .URL encoding instead .JSON

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati this works perfect for me. I tried every possible solution but didn't work only changing .JSON to .URL works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your receiving JSON data.

Change your `Content-Type` `text/html` to `application/json`.

**Edit:**

I have explain the possible reasons when status code is `200` OK, Still data shows `null` in below answer.

[xcode NSURLConnection post return 200 but NSData always null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841299/xcode-nsurlconnection-post-return-200-but-nsdata-always-null/26841896#26841896)

Comment: request--------------------------------------------------->

<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f845bd6c5d0> { URL: http://XXX/test/index/test, headers: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
} }  Content-Type is application/json.

Comment: init request with "encoding:ParameterEncoding.JSON" all type will be auto configure by Alamofire

Comment: You mean to say you are passing `application/json` in request. If yes, then you can see that your response header show `text/html`.

Comment: request--》headers: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";

response----->

Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f845bd63cb0> { URL: http://xxx/test/index/test } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 22;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 16 Oct 2014 06:23:23 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.12";
} })

Comment: as your said, it is all right, but print empty:
   php code“ echo json_encode(array('data'=>$_REQUEST));”

Comment: I still suggest you to check why `Content-Type` is different for request and response? Is there an API or server configuration then please check.

Comment: @JNYJ - Here is another answer, may help you to more clear understanding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841299/xcode-nsurlconnection-post-return-200-but-nsdata-always-null/26841896#26841896

Answer (score 0):

changing .JSON to .URL works perfect in encoding.

I tried every possible solution but didn't work only changing .JSON to .URL works perfect. Thanks saurabh.

Answer (score 0):

i also have same problem , but when i change .URL encoding From .JSON encoding and it's work perfectly!