# xcode NSURLConnection post return 200 but NSData always null?

Tags: ios, xcode, post

```
NSString *post = @"maxor=123&minor=123";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xavier-beacon.appspot.com/result4.jsp"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]  ;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connect start];
```

===================================================================================================

```
- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{   
    NSLog(@"state------%d", status);

}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData: (NSData *) incomingData
{    
    NSLog(@"data---%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData: incomingData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

}
```

the following log is always :
(state-------200)
(data---null)

It is easy to use http://xavier-beacon.appspot.com/result4.jsp?maxor=123&minor=123   to get the response data on the chrome/IE/Firefox

but use xcode in iphone always return state=200 and data=null QAQ...

Who can tell me how can i fix this problem...Plz T_T

Comment: Have tried by changing the content-type? If you have json data than you should set @"application/json" in `Content-Type`.

Comment: the current response just a short string  --->  |||||123|||||123|||||
               ,but the iphone always get the  "null" ;

Comment: this is the server code ----> 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=BIG5" pageEncoding="BIG5"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=BIG5">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
|||||123|||||123|||||
</body>
</html>

Comment: Here `Content-Type` is `text/html`. So replace `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with `text/html` and than check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code 200 shows that you have now active and successful connection with the server. But that does not mean that you will get data successfully. There are some points needs to be take care:

1. Your request should match `Content-Type` required on server. If it is not match you will not receive data or invalid data
2. Make sure which method you have called `GET` or `POST`.
3. Some web-services are also required specific `user-agent`, So if it required check for user-agent also
4. Parameter values: Even if you get success code - The datatype values required to server some time mis lead to you. Most common possible datatype mis match are `bool`, `int` and `float`. It is essential to check that you have pass exact datatype value. e.g. 1 is consider as `int` and also as a `bool` value.
5. Encoding Scheme: You must have to parse receive data with exactly same encoding scheme as per server specification.

**Edit:**

In your case you just need to change `encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding`.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData: (NSData *) incomingData
{
    NSLog(@"data---%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData: incomingData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

}
```

Replace above method with your code.

Comment: @鍾豐吉 - I figure out your problem. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`-connection:didReceiveData:` might get called multiple times during the download process.

You should hold an instance of `NSMutableData` wich you initiate in `-connection:didReceiveResponse`.

Then you append the data and allocate the string when the connection finishes:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [[self receivedData] appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"data---%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self receivedData] encoding:NSURF8StringEncoding]);
    self.receivedData = nil;
}
```

I would recommend using something like [JWURLConnection](https://github.com/julian-weinert/JWURLConnection) but if you really want to implement it on your own you could check the source code.