# Json Parsing from NSURLResponse in IOS

Tags: ios, json, nshttpurlresponse

I am getting response

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa151d20> { URL: http://abcdxyz/api } { status code: 200, headers {
"Content-Length" = 0;
"Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Tue, 11 Nov 2014 06:57:01 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
```

} }

Now Can u guys please help me hw will i get JSON Object from this Response. Thanks.

Comment: Visit this answer, it may help to clear things - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841299/xcode-nsurlconnection-post-return-200-but-nsdata-always-null/26841896#26841896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me (except that you're making a synchronous request, but that's beside the point here.) You're getting the status code 200, which means your request was successful. If you didn't get the data you expected in the response, you'll need to check the documentation for this API to see what the expected response should be. It could be that the server returns just a simple "OK" -- which is pretty much what you're getting.

If the docs don't answer your question, try to ask someone who knows about this particular web service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I had a problem regarding that dictionary format.. :-)